# Posting file to a remote PC C#

Tags: c#-4.0, file-upload

I need to post a text file to a remote PC. I know of one way which is to setup a ftp server on remote PC but i want to map a drive of remote PC to my computer and then post the file there using C#. In other words i want to know how can i share a folder on remote PC with my computer so i can post a file there using C#.

I want to know how network drive mapping is done

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: How to post a file to remote desktop using C# .

Comment: and if mapping drive of remote desktop is simplest solution how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open remote desktop
- Click options (bottom left on the window)
- Goto Local Resources tab
- Under 'Local devides and resources' (bottom of the page), click 'More'.

Here you can map any local drive for the remote session, and they will appear on the remote computer's 'My Computer' when you connect.

**UPDATE**

You can simply have a network share configured on the remote machine, and your C# code can write to that folder.

Your path will look like `\\ComputerName\PublicShare\folder\structure\you\want`

Or, you can have a fully blown client-server system, where you have a client running on the remote machine, connecting to the server instance on your machine, where your 'server' posts the contents of the file to the client through your API, and the client decides (using its configuration) where to write the file.

Which one to use, depends on your requirement. Network share is simple and easy to setup. Client-server system is a lot of code, but flexible enough to have a configuration, and security, and can be extended to allow file sharing over the internet.

Comment: I want the opposite actually i want a folder from remote desktop shared with my local computer . the basic thing i am trying to achieve is post a text file to remote desktop using C# code

Comment: Sorry, I don't know whether that's possible. If the 2 computers are on the same network, you can setup a network share and post to that, regardless of a RDP session. Please explain how the file posting mixes with remote desktop. I can understand that you need to send a file to another machine, but how does remote desktop come in to play ? Have you considered transferring the file over the internet ? using a server in the middle ?

Comment: Sorry i just figured out my question is ambiguous . I currently want to send file to another computer on same network but if you can give some link to post file to computer on another network how would it be done

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to map a drive.

You can just write a file to `\\ComputerName\ShareName\Subfolder\File.ext` the same way you write any other file.

Comment: ohh ok thanks and how to put credentials in while posting the file because the other computer has to be logged on using password ( or if folder is shared i do not need to enter any credentials )

Comment: @ffayyaz: As long as the user you're running as exists (with the same password) on the other machine and has write access to that path, it will just work.